# burn black the dish; right meaning

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm interested to know if it is correct to say the phrase "burn black" in this sentence:

> I forget to turn off the oven and **burn black** my dinner.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a "blackened" relating to food, but it is usually an intentional result. For example "*blackened* fish".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just say "I **forgot** to turn off the oven and **burned/burnt** my dinner."

In American English, "burned" is more commonly used as a verb, and "burnt" is normally used only as an adjective (Example: This toast is burnt).

In British English, both "burned" and "burnt" are used interchangeably as verbs, and "burnt" is also used as an adjective.

Also, "forgot" is the past tense of "forget".

Sources:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6716/when-would-one-use-burnt-and-when-would-burned-be-more-appropriate

http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/burnt-vs-burned.2292590/

http://grammarist.com/usage/burned-burnt/

http://theydiffer.com/difference-between-burned-and-burnt/

https://www.englishforums.com/English/BurntBurned/vwvbn/post.htm

http://www.onestopenglish.com/methodology/ask-the-experts/vocabulary-questions/vocabulary-while-whilst-burned-burnt/146420.article

http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/burned-versus-burnt

Comment: Oops, I just noticed that I typed one of the links twice. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I have not heard such a wording. I would say:

> I *forgot* to turn off the oven and **burned** my dinner (until it was black).

(both tenses have to match, as @Potato Chip pointed out)

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to turn off the oven and burned my dinner black.

I burned my dinner black.  Black is the complement of 'my dinner'.

We will watch the flames burn auburn on the mountain side.

Auburn is the complement of 'Flames'.

My dinner was burned black. 
I burned my dinner black. 
The sun burned red in the sky. 
His eyes burned red. Etc.